# Recoger datos e incrementar

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo esta función Jquery-Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #fecha, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
                $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#acro_proyecto').val() + "-" + $('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + $('#num_documento').val() + "-(" + $('#idioma').val() + ")");
            });
        });
```

Habría alguna manera de que el

> nº documento

se incrementara solo cada vez que se repetiera el

> acro_proyecto

El formulario del cual recoge los datos es el siguiente:

```
<form class="contacto" id="form1" action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
<table>
      <tr>
          <th style="text-align:left;">Titulo del Documento</th>
          <td width="50%"><input class="form-control titulodocumento" type="text" name="titulo_documento" id="titulo_documento" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('titulo_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

          <th style="text-align:center;">Acronimo Proyecto</th>
          <td width="50%">
                         <select class="form-control" id="acro_proyecto" name="acro_proyecto" required>

                         <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?> </option>
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_proyecto from proyectos');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option>' . $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                           </select>
           </td>
           <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="proyecto"  id="proyecto" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Estado</th>
        <td width="50%"><input class="form-control estado" type="text" name="estado" id="estado" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('estado') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

         <th style="text-align:left;">Numero de documento</th>
         <td width="50%"><input class="form-control numerodocumento" type="text" name="num_documento" id="num_documento" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('num_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Idioma</th>
              <td><select class="form-control" id="idioma" name="idioma" required>
                  <option value=""><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('idioma') : ''; ?></option>
                                    <option value="E">Inglés</option>
                                    <option value="S">Español</option>
                                    <option value="P">Portugués</option>
                                </select>


               <th style="text-align:left;">Version</th>
               <td width="50%"><input class="form-control version" type="text" name="version" id="version" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('version') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
               <th style="text-align:left;">Revision</th>
               <td width="50%"><input class="form-control revision" type="text" name="revision" id="revision" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('revision') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

                <th style="text-align:left;">Descripcion</th>
                <td width="50%"><input class="form-control descripcion" type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('descripcion') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Fecha</th>
            <td width="50%"><input class="form-control fecha" type="date" name="fecha"  id="fecha" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('fecha') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de documento</th>
           <td width="50%">
                           <select class="form-control" name="acro_documento" id="acro_documento"  onchange="change_documento();" required>
                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('tipo_documento') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('tipo_documento') : ''; ?> </option>    
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select distinct acro_documento from tipodocumentos order by acro_documento');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        ?>
                                        echo <option value="<?php echo $row['acro_documento']; ?>"><?php echo $row['acro_documento']; ?> </option>
                                    <?php }
                                    ?>

                                </select> 
                            </td>


                            <th style="text-align:center;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>                   
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control" name="acro_subcategoria" id="acro_subcategoria" required>
                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('subcategoria') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('subcategoria') : ''; ?> </option>    
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('subcategoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="tipo_documento" id="tipo_documento" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('tipo_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:abrir('tipodocumentos.php')">Tipos de documento</a>
                            </td>
                            <th>
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:abrir('subcategoria1.php')">Subcategorias</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </th>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Confidencialidad</th>
                            <td width="50%"><input class="form-control confidencialidad" type="text" name="confidencialidad" id="confidencialidad" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('confidencialidad') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Usuario</th>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control" id="acro_usuario1" name="acro_usuario1" required>
                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?> </option>    
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from usuarios');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option name="' .
                                        ($row['acro_usuario']) . '">' .
                                        (
                                        $row['acro_usuario'] . '(' .
                                        $row['nombre'] . ' ' .
                                        $row['apellidos'] . ')'
                                        ) . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>


                            <th style="text-align:left;">Aprobado por</th>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control" id="aprobado_por1" name="aprobado_por1" required>

                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('aprobado_por') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('aprobado_por') : ''; ?> </option>
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from usuarios');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option name="' .
                                        ($row['acro_usuario']) . '">' .
                                        (
                                        $row['acro_usuario'] . '(' .
                                        $row['nombre'] . ' ' .
                                        $row['apellidos'] . ')'
                                        ) . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="aprobado_por" id="aprobado_por" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('aprobado_por') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="acro_usuario" id="acro_usuario" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Autorizado por</th>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control" id="autorizado_por1" name="autorizado_por1" required>

                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('autorizado_por') : ''; ?>"> <?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('autorizado_por') : ''; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from usuarios');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option name="' .
                                        ($row['acro_usuario']) . '">' .
                                        (
                                        $row['acro_usuario'] . '(' .
                                        $row['nombre'] . ' ' .
                                        $row['apellidos'] . ')'
                                        ) . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>


                            <th style="text-align:left;">Revisor</th>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control"id="revisor1" name="revisor1" required>

                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('revisor') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('revisor') : ''; ?> </option>
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from usuarios');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option name="' .
                                        ($row['acro_usuario']) . '">' .
                                        (
                                        $row['acro_usuario'] . '(' .
                                        $row['nombre'] . ' ' .
                                        $row['apellidos'] . ')'
                                        ) . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="revisor" id="revisor" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('revisor') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="autorizado_por" id="autorizado_por" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('autorizado_por') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Compañía</th>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <select class="form-control" id="compania1" name="compania1" required>

                                    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?> </option>
                                    <?php
                                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
                                    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acronimo from compania');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option>' . $row['acronimo'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="0%"><input type="hidden" name="compania" id="compania" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Código del proyecto</th>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo_proyecto"   id="codigo_proyecto"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('codigo_proyecto') : ''; ?>" readonly="" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="boton" value="Guardar" /></td>
                            <td colspan="2"> 
                                <a href="index.php">
                                    <input type="submit" class="button_active" value="Limpiar" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Se supone que el último campo va recogiendo los datos de lo introducido en este form, pero claro el numero de documento se debe de poner a mano y lo que quiero es que si ponga solo, pero si ya existe un proyecto con 1 en numero de documento automaticamente pase al 2, no se si se puede hacer o no.

Gracia spor la ayuda.

Comment: creo que podria hacer un each para el el num_documento y utiliizar el indice + 1

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo completo asi poder entender mejor tu pregunta

Comment: @DionisioChavez ya lo hice, es un form bastante extenso pero puse el form entero más aqui lo puedne ver funcional 'https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/xkjz4hzt/1/'